# Available programs

Tags: apps

I was interested with this OS, but sadly I lack experience with Linux (except a little bit with ubuntu).
And now I have a question: What programs are available on this OS?
Does any Linux based program will work?
If not, where I could find full list of available programs :)
Thanks, and btw, OS looks very nice ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost all Ubuntu programs work with elementary OS. So you can install anything you like from the software center :)

Remember to mark this as answer if it is the solution to your question

Answer (score 0):

As Suici Doga said, almost all Ubuntu programs work, but in personal experience, almost all with Terminal install. Some programs from Software Center didn't worked well with me.

You can also check this page https://quassy.github.io/elementary-apps/

They are specific for elementary OS.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that ! Sadly I can't select 2 answers. I will probably try this OS when my session will end and I won't need windows for summer ^^

Comment: It's okay, I just wanted to help, that's it. I hope the list will get more apps soon. :)